# How to label complex edges with graph library?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I would like to use `graph` TikZ-library from CVS version ([sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/develop) or [tlcontrib](http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/cgi-bin/package.cgi/ruid=3573839512/action=view/id=568)) to draw flowcharts. Something like the one shown in chapter 5 from TikZ manual. In this tutorial, some styles are declared to easily draw loops and corners between nodes. I would like to add some label to this lines but `edge label` option doesn't work with these kind of edges. It seems to work with straight paths but not with complex ones.

Next example shows the problem:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,graphs,matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',
    font=\sffamily\small,
    every node/.style={align=center},
    skip loop left/.style={to path={-- ++(-#1,0)|- (\tikztotarget)}},
    skip loop right/.style={to path={-- ++(#1,0)|- (\tikztotarget)}},
    hv path/.style ={to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}},
   vh path/.style ={to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}},
]

\matrix[column sep=1cm,row sep=1cm] (mymatrix)  {
\coordinate (A11) {}; & \node[draw] (A12) {A12};\\
\node[draw] (A21) {A21}; & \coordinate (A22) {};\\
};

\graph[use existing nodes] {
 A21->[edge label=A]A12;
 A21->[hv path, edge label=B] A12;  %<- this label is not shown
 A21--[edge label=C]A11->A12; 
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result shows labels A and C, but not B. Label C is shown because the edge is divided into two straight edges. I can always use something like that, but do you know a better solution?

[image]

Comment: You should perhaps mention that you're using a CVS version of PGF, and possibly where that can be found, as the `graph` library isn't yet in the version of PGF that is on CTAN. (Or am I just blind/mistaken?)

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Ups! Yes I forgot to mention it. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Maybe the `python` package [`algoflow`](https://github.com/c-fos/algoflow) that exports `tikz` flowcharts could also prove handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem doesn’t have anything to do with `graphs` or the library. The `to path`s are missing their nodes. You need to add `\tikztonodes` after the target coordinate of the path operatore you want to add the nodes to.

```
hv path/.style ={to path={-| (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
vh path/.style ={to path={|- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
```

I also switched to the `arrows.meta` library (`stealth` becomes `Stealth`) since the libraries `arrows` and `arrows.spaced` are now depecrated (but still available of course).

---

Though it seem that a new bug has been introduced which can be seen with

```
A21 -- [edge label=C] A11 -> A12;
```

as the edge from `A21` to `A11` gets an arrow tip even if `<-` is used anywhere on that graph.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,graphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  >=Stealth,
  font=\sffamily\small,
  every node/.style={align=center},
  hv path/.style ={to path={-| (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
  vh path/.style ={to path={|- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
]

\matrix[column sep=1cm,row sep=1cm] (mymatrix)  {
  \coordinate (A11);       & \node[draw] (A12) {A12}; \\
  \node[draw] (A21) {A21}; & \coordinate (A22);       \\
};

\graph[use existing nodes] {
 A21 -> [edge label=A]A12;
 A21 -> [hv path, near end, edge label'=B] A12;
 A21 -- [edge label=C] A11 -> A12; 
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're only trying to create flow-charts, it would be much easier if you use pure tikz without a library. Here's an example from the tikz example site (slightly modified).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\begin{document}

  \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=gray!20, 
  text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
  \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=gray!15, 
  text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
  \tikzstyle{altblock} = [rectangle, draw, fill=gray!15, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners=6pt, minimum height=2em]
  \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
  \tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=gray!10, node distance=3cm,
  minimum height=2em]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm, auto,scale=0.75,transform shape]
    % Place nodes
    \node [altblock] (init) {initialize};
    \node [cloud, left of=init] (expert) {expert};
    \node [cloud, right of=init] (system) {system};
    \node [decision, below of=init] (identify) {Was successful?};
    \node [block, below of=identify] (evaluate) {evaluate candidate models};
    \node [block, left of=evaluate, node distance=3cm] (update) {update model};
    \node [decision, below of=evaluate] (decide) {is best candidate better?};
    \node [block, below of=decide, node distance=3cm] (stop) {stop};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (identify);
    \path [line] (identify) -- node[auto] {yes} (evaluate);
    \path [line] (identify) -| node[auto,right] {no} (system);
    \path [line] (evaluate) -- (decide);
    \path [line] (decide) -| node [near start] {yes} (update);
    \path [line] (update) |- (identify);
    \path [line] (decide) -- node {no}(stop);
    \path [line,dashed] (expert) -- (init);
    \path [line,dashed] (system) -- (init);
    %\path [line,dashed] (system) |- (evaluate);
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Here's the output for this:

[image]